# What should a link extension relation type URI point to in a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, http-headers, standards, rel

I've been designing an API recently that needs to be RESTful, and have managed to define a system that uses exclusively HTTP headers and query string parameters to define meta data so that the body of responses is free to just be actual resource data only.

However I'm now thinking about links for HATEOAS, and due to wanting to keep everything in HTTP headers or query string parameters I've decided on using the HTTP `Link` header field.

This has brought up a question about the `rel` attribute that I'm having trouble finding a direct answer for.

My idea is that for collections of resources one of the `Link`s that will be sent in a response will be something like: `Link: <https://api.domain.com/things/{id}>; rel="..."`

This would allow a client to use simple string expansion, as defined in [RFC6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), to create a correct resource URI for each resource in a collection without me having to embed meta data into each resource and without the client needing to know anything other than the URI template and the resource ID.

However, I'm not sure what the `rel` should be here, or what it should point to.

In [RFC5988](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5988#section-4.2), it says that an extension relation type must be a URI and:

> Although the URI can point to a
> resource that contains a definition of the semantics of the relation
> type, clients SHOULD NOT automatically access that resource to avoid
> overburdening its server.

My question is, what should the definition look like in a RESTful API?

By the looks of it I could just make the `rel` something like `https://api.domain.com/media/thing`, or something like that.

But then what should the actual definition content be?

It looks like it could technically be anything, for example a plain text document with a short explanation.

Is there any RESTful standard for these kinds of `rel` attributes and what they should point to?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Richardson's Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3) level 3, `rel` seems to be representing the name of the published link/relationship. In your case that might translate to `curie:thing-by-id` (provided you're using curies as suggested in the proposed HAL [draft](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-03#section-8.2)), for example. The idea is that the client could search a link by its name (`rel`), without peering into the actual `url`.

Comment: So it looks like the HAL draft gives a nice suggestion that the rel URI should point to an HTML page with documentation on the relation, and CURIEs would be used to cut down on data transfer size, and provide a consistent key for clients to lookup to retrieve an href for that relation, even if the rel URI itself were to change.

Basically, use the rel to point to HTML docs, use a CURIE to make href lookup with a rel as the key more dependable.

Is that right?

If I have understood correctly then I think this answers my question quite nicely, but I will wait for confirmation.

Comment: yep, that's pretty much my understanding of it, too

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any RESTful standard for these kinds of rel attributes and what they should point to?

I don't know of an *authoritative* answer, but it is probably worth noticing that link relations that are [registered with IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) reference the standards document that describes the link.

For example, in the registry, the "item" and "collection" relations both reference [RFC 6573](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6573.html).  Which, you will notice, is pretty darn close to a "a plain text document with a short explanation."

If the media type of your documentation supports anchors, then you could use a link directly to the secondary resource as your link relation

```
Link: <https://api.domain.com/things/2>; rel="https://api.domain.com/link-relations#foo"
```